# Альтернативные wysiwyg activity редакторы?

Tags: wysiwyg, activity, android

Есть  альтернативы тому, что есть в Eclipse и IntelliJ IDEA? html + phonehap не предлагать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем вас эти двое не устроили? Блажь?

Имхо, лучше для разработчика под андроид чем Eclipse с ADT или IDEA 12 ничего нет.
Последняя так прекрасна во всех смыслах. Быстрый кодинг, интеграция с андроидом из коробки, интеграция с Git и Mercurial, системами сборки и кучей всего всего. Единственное, что удрачает так это непривычные типы проектов(модули, сами проекты), что лично мне кажется неявным. А в остальном, вы жируете:)

NetBeans - хорошая среда, но нет такой поддержки Андроида. Да и немного тормознее, как кажется по личным ощущениям.

Ну если уж так хочется хардкора, то можете создавать андроид-проекты из командной строки(android.bat) и использовать любую среду IDE или редактор, благо их очень много и гугл с запросом "IDE" или "Java IDE" вам найдет пару десятков.

Answer (score 1):

Monodevelop.

С-[качать](http://monodevelop.com/Download) под все платформы.

Comment: Мне лишь альтернативный wysiwyg нужен, менять язык (java) мне не охото

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Java - тут не то?

Comment: @ShockWave Но это явно танцы с бубном. Что нибудь по проще есть?